# paste image to excel file using APACHE POI in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using APACHE POI to write data in an excel file. This works great
Now I need to paste an image in the excel file also, I am not sure how would I do that using APACHE POI.

The image(bar/pie chart) is generated dynamically by the tool it self, which is in JAVA. Following is the code which copies the image to clipboard.

```
// copy text data to clipboard
                ImageAndTextSelection sel = new ImageAndTextSelection(pieImg, strText);
                Clipboard clippy = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                clippy.setContents(sel, null);
```

Comment: I know that reading the documentation isn't considered very cool these days, but [what happens if you go to the Apache POI documentation and read the cunningly titled section on adding Images](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images)?

Comment: I saw that. That's for adding an external image file. I already have a file which was generated by java tool and copied to clipboard. I am not sure how would I copy that.

Comment: Apache POI doesn't care where the image comes from, it just needs an InputStream. Simply grab your image as a stream, or as bytes that you wrap as a ByteArrayInputStream, and follow the instructions